# How do I format DateTime with UTC timezone offset?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

What type of date format is this?

```
2020-03-26T00:57:08.000+08:00
```

I'm using [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();

 print(dateTime.toIso8601String());
 print(dateTime.toLocal());
 print(dateTime.toUtc());
```

Output

```
I/flutter (20667): 2020-03-26T01:34:20.826589
I/flutter (20667): 2020-03-26 01:34:20.826589
I/flutter (20667): 2020-03-25 17:34:20.826589Z
```

I would like to have a date format like the first output I show, which has the +08:00 behind. Which should I use?

Comment: From where do you get the initial date from? It does not look like a valid date format to me, what's the + stands for?

Comment: @StefanoSaitta Get from a backend guy. Can we generate this kind of format in frontend?

Comment: That +08:00 seems to stand for Time zone offset https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/timeZoneOffset.html

Comment: @StefanoSaitta toIso8601String + zone offset?

Comment: Looks like so, are you attempting to parse it?

Comment: @StefanoSaitta yes. I want the format looked exactly  the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210384/discussion-between-stefano-saitta-and-tony).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no direct way of getting that kind of date format as of now. There is a work-around.

- Add the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package
- import it to your file using `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`
- Write the following code:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.now();
var val      = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(dateTime);
var offset   = dateTime.timeZoneOffset;
var hours    = offset.inHours > 0 ? offset.inHours : 1; // For fixing divide by 0

if (!offset.isNegative) {
  val = val +
      "+" +
      offset.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0') +
      ":" +
      (offset.inMinutes % (hours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
} else {
  val = val +
      "-" +
      (-offset.inHours).toString().padLeft(2, '0') +
      ":" +
      (offset.inMinutes % (hours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
}
print(val);
```

Comment: There is a small bug in this. When offset is negative, this code will never produce 2 digits hour. I change the negative part to: returnString = returnString +
        "-" +
        (-offset.inHours).toString().padLeft(2, '0') +
        ":" +
        (offset.inMinutes % (hoursDivision * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

Answer (score 6):

---

> What date format is this?
> "2020-03-26T00:57:08.000+08:00"

This date-time format follows the RFC 3339 standard, and more generally the ISO 8601 standard. The letter "T" is known as the time designator. The "+08:00" is known as the UTC timezone offset.

---

> I would like to have a date format [...], which has the +08:00 behind

To the date-time, you can append the UTC hour and minute offsets:

```dart
// import 'package:intl/intl.dart' as intl show DateFormat;

void main() {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  Duration offset = now.timeZoneOffset;

  // ----------
  String dateTime = now.toIso8601String();
  // - or -
  // String dateTime = intl.DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(now);
  // ----------
  String utcHourOffset = (offset.isNegative ? '-' : '+') +
    offset.inHours.abs().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  String utcMinuteOffset = (offset.inMinutes - offset.inHours * 60)
    .toString().padLeft(2, '0');

  String dateTimeWithOffset = '$dateTime$utcHourOffset:$utcMinuteOffset';
  print(dateTimeWithOffset);
}
```

---

> I'm using DateFormat class

DateFormat (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) does not format a UTC timezone offset. And while the letter "Z" in the documentation appears to provide the UTC timezone offset, it's reserved, and you can not use `DateFormat("Z")` as that throws an Unimplemented Error (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/UnimplementedError-class.html). Note that "Z" (pronounced phonetically as "zulu") stands for zero meridian time, and has a UTC timezone offset of +0:00.

---

Comment: Careful with the 'inHours' expression, as offsets can be half an hour

Comment: @JDumont - Good point. Updated my answer to include UTC offsets with minutes, and now crying because of how much code is needed 

Answer (score 2):

> What type of date format is this?

This format is UTC + timezone offset.

That +08:00 is the time zone's offset that has already been added.

Seems like `DateTime` doesn't contain timezone information, so, you can't create a DateTime in a specific timezone. Only the timezone of your system and UTC are available.

Is important to say also that `DateTime` support timezone offset for parsing, but normalizes it to UTC or local time.

So since this is UTC you can probably format it using `toUtc` or `toLocal` and the receiver will be able to parse it.

With that said, you can simply parse it like this:

```dart
DateTime.parse("2020-03-26T00:57:08.000+08:00")
```

Comment: Like this ?`DateTime.parse(dateTime.toUtc()+ dateTime.zone Offset)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods `toLocal()` and `toUtc()` to get the equivalent date/time value specified in the other time zone

read more https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this in flutter

Using package: intl: ^0.17.0

```
Text(DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(<your date format for e.g. 2022-09-08T19:20:40.650367+05:30>.toLocal())
```

Output:

```
Sep 8, 2022 7:20 PM
```

Comment: Sorry, the question asked for "with UTC timezone offset"...