# how to get the utc time of an analog clock in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I got a package that you can easily use to create a clock. problem is, the documentation isn't really well presented. this is the code below, how do I edit the code so the clock shows me the date of different locations. for example I want to create two clocks. one for UTC -5 and another for UTC +1. i don't want the current date of the location of the phone

```
import 'package:analog_clock/analog_clock.dart';


AnalogClock(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        shape: BoxShape.circle),
    width: 150.0,
    isLive: true,
    hourHandColor: Colors.black,
    minuteHandColor: Colors.black,
    showSecondHand: false,
    numberColor: Colors.black87,
    showNumbers: true,
    textScaleFactor: 1.4,
    showTicks: false,
    showDigitalClock: false,
    datetime: DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 9, 12, 15),
    );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format DateTime with UTC timezone offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60854312/how-do-i-format-datetime-with-utc-timezone-offset)

Comment: If you want to show the local time in different timezones, use [`package:timezone`](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone).

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this package but I think you may play around with `datetime` property.

The `DateTime` in Flutter has some helpful helpers to convert it to and from UTC, you may read this [article](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-convert-utc-time-to-local-time-and-vice-versa/) about that.

Comment: i've gone thorugh it but still dont understand. i just want to show the time of a particular timezone but it states DateTime.utc(2022, 2, 3, 10, 30, 45);. I don't want to state the date. i just want the time of that particular location

Comment: What about playing around with something like `datetime: DateTime.now().toUtc()`?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the analog_clock plugin accepts only DateTime. So we must pass irrespective of the zone. So we need to just accommodate the UTC.
Guess this works for you.

```
import 'package:analog_clock/analog_clock.dart';

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: -5, minutes: 00)).toUtc();
AnalogClock(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        shape: BoxShape.circle),
    width: 150.0,
    isLive: true,
    hourHandColor: Colors.black,
    minuteHandColor: Colors.black,
    showSecondHand: false,
    numberColor: Colors.black87,
    showNumbers: true,
    textScaleFactor: 1.4,
    showTicks: false,
    showDigitalClock: false,
    datetime: dateTime,
    );
```